# What is the output of the following code? (exception handling c++)

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

Student here. I am trying to learn the basics of the exception handling in c++ and a got a piece of code which confuses me. Can someone please explain me why the output is 120 ? Also, I don't understand why i have in the body of the exec() func { X, x}. What does {} do here? Thank you !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X(void){
       cout<<1;
    }
    ~X(void){
       cout<<2;
    }
};

void exec(){
   {
    X x;
   }
   throw string("0");
}

int main() 
{
    try{
       exec();
    }catch(string &s){
    cout<<s;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*What is the output of the following code?*" did you run it to see? "*The function exec() is a bit fuzzy for me*" what does this mean? What don't you understand? Your question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: "*What does {} do here?*" - it just creates an addition scope inside of `exec()`.  The `X` object is being created inside that scope and will be destroyed when that scope ends, before the `throw` is reached. Without the extra scope, the object would be destroyed when `exec()` exits, during stack winding due to the `throw`.

Comment: Start at `main`, follow through `exec` (constructor and destructor of `x`), follow from `throw` to `catch`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau gotcha, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually run the code, you will see the output for yourself:

> 120

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/7H9xaN)

What is happening is this:

1. `main()` enters the `try` block and calls `exec()`.
2. `exec()` creates a nested scope, creating and destroying an `X` object in that scope.  The constructor and destructor of that object print to `cout`, so you see `1` and `2`, respectively.
3. after the scope ends, a new `std::string` object is created and passed to `throw`. The string's content is `"0"`.
4. `throw` searches the call stack for a `catch` block that can handle the `std::string` object.  Such a `catch` is in `main()`.
5. the call stack for `exec()` is unwound, and execution jumps to the found `catch` block.
6. the `std::string` is printed to `cout`, so you see `0`.
7. the `catch` block ends, `main()` exits, and the program terminates.